# Probability that the detector lasts longer than 2 years

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> There is a detector in a satellite orbiting the earth. The lifetime
>   (in years) of the detector is a random number $X$, that has
>   exponential distribution with parameter 1/2. What is the probability
>   that the detector lasts longer than 2 years?

**Solution attempt:**

$${\text{P}}({\text{detector lasts longer than 2 years)}} = 1 - {\text{P(detector lasts no more than 2 years)}}$$
$${\text{P}}({\text{detector lasts longer than 2 years)}} = 1 - 0.5 \cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^2 {{e^{ - 0.5x}}}  \approx 0.01279$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Having a sum does not make sense - this is not the Poisson distribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the cumulative distribution function of an exponentially distributed random variable is $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = 1 - e^{-\lambda x},$$ where $\lambda$ is a rate parameter.  So, the probability that the lifetime exceeds $2$ is $$\Pr[X > 2] = e^{-2\lambda}.$$  The problem is that when the question says "$X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1/2$," it is not clear whether they mean that this parameter is a rate parameter, or a scale parameter; i.e., do they mean $\lambda = 1/2$, or $1/\lambda = 1/2$?  This is ambiguous.